# Iterations on a string, 'expression must have a pointer-to-object type' error

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a problem doing iterations on a string.

Function input:

1. a string of numbers with no spaces in between, in the range of [-9,9], and up to 10 numbers (means maximum 20 chars long if every number is negative).
2. the size of the string.

The function needs to create an array of the numbers.

For example if I get the input "809-2-3", my new array needs to be - [8,0,9,-2,-3].

in my code, I get the error 'expression must have a pointer-to-object type', and I don't understand it.

This is the code I wrote:

```
void separate_nums(char str, int str_len)
{
    int new_arr[20];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= str_len - 1; i++)//run through the string
    {
        if (str[i] == '-') //if the char is -, take minus of the next char. Then increase index by one so you'll get to the next number
        {
            new_arr[i] = -str[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
        else
            new_arr[i] = str[i];
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are they definitely single-digit integers?  Because if they aren't then you can't do this.

Comment: From your example it seems you can make the assumption that all values are between -9 and 9. That means if you see two consecutive digits, you never need to interpret them as part of the same number. But - consult the textbook or the person who gave you this assignment to make sure. (I won't write the relevant code for you, since this sounds like a teaching exercise you got, and you should solve it yourself...)

Comment: Honestly this sounds like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/389680)!  Why have you got yourself into a situation where you're getting the input from the user in such a format?  Why not just loop over the 'input' function and ask the users to enter the integers separately in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

First, an array is needed.

1. Count the number of digits (`n`).
2. Allocate an array which can hold `n` numbers.

Next, it's just a question of looking at the characters of the string one at a time. Any time a `-` is encountered, simply use the next character, but negate it.

1. Initialize a variable identifying the next character to parse.
2. Loop for each element of the array,

   1. Assume the number isn't negative.
   2. If the next character is a `-`,

      1. The number is negative.
      2. Move to the next character.
   3. Convert the next digit to a number.
   4. If the number should be negative,

      1. Negate the number.
   5. Store the number in the current array element.
   6. Move to the next character.

Of course, we need to make sure the user doesn't provide garbage. This is left to you to handle.